# R Markdown adding image tags after include_graphics

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using R Markdown to include some images into a PDF. Everything is working fine, but there is a 5.bb after every single jpeg insert. I think it might be an image tag, but am unsure. Here is the code I am using and screen shot of the error:

```
library(knitr)
myimages<-("~/Dropbox/LifeExp/graphics/life-page8 5.jpeg")
include_graphics(myimages)
```

[image: image tags?]

Comment: Give us some more details ... your yaml header, a MWE, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try delete blank spaces in name file and code chunk. Use "_" instead.